Prefixing defaultLocale in NextJS triggers build error
I follow NextJS documentation on Prefixing defaultLocale however, I'm facing build error when I run yarn build
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /: /default
        /_error: /404
        /_error: /500
        /_error: /default/404
        /_error: /default/500
        /about: /default/about
        /apply: /default/apply
        ...

I suspect that it has to do with getStaticProps and locale to fetch some of my content.
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }: { locale: string }) {
  const lang = locale.split("-")[0] as Locale;
  const pageData = apply[lang];
  return {
    props: {
      pageData,
    },
  };
}

I tried to conditionally update the content of lang as such:
const lang = locale !== 'default' ? locale.split("-")[0] as Locale : 'fr' as Locale;

I still get the error.

After some more digging, it seems that it is a know issue. FWIW, here's my solution.
I kept the logic provided in Next JS documentation. But since I'm using locale in my pages to pull the content and a context provider for passing locale in some components, here's the workaround:
In the NextJS pages where I'm using getStaticPropsor getServerSideProps, I kept the ternary condition I had initially:
const lang = locale !== 'default' ? locale.split("-")[0] as Locale : 'fr' as Locale;

I updated LangContext (my context provider) in _app.tsx to account for default as such:
<LangContext.Provider value={ locale === "default" ? "fr" : locale || "fr" }>
...
</LangContext.Provider>

I'm aware that it is not the most ideal solution, but it appears I'm not the only one struggling with this and there is no other option in the current state of NextJS.
